# JPanel redraw problem

Tags: java, swing

I have `JFrame`, and I added my `JPanel` class with `paintComponent()` method. For example I drawed red rectangle, and after some action I want to draw green oval. I tried to call `repaint()` method in `JPanel` but nothing happens. Help me please!

**UPDATE:** It's just example code

```
public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private Container content;
private MyPanel em; 
private JButton btn;
    Test() {
        super("test");
        content = getContentPane();
        em = new MyPanel();
        conent.add(em);
        btn = new JButton("Draw");  
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        content.add(btn);   
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                em.setShape("oval");
    }           

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
private String shape = "rectangle";
    MyPanel()
    {
    }
    setShape(String shape){
        this.shape = shape;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(shape == "rectanle")
          g.drawRectangle(100,25,100,200);


        }
        else if(shape == "oval"){
           g.drawOval(100, 25, 175, 175);
        }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to begin to answer it. You'll need to post code (the smallest possible amount of code that reproduces the problem), and details of what behaviour you expect to see, what you actually see, and what you think the problem might be.

Comment: Did you run your program with the -DPleaseRepaintMyPanelPromptly flag?

Comment: There are quite a few mistakes here such that I'm not going to try to post an answer yet.  First off, String comparison must always use `.equals` ( `if (shape.equals("rectangle") { ...` ).  Second you have typos (`rectanle`).  Which leads to the second fix: always use a constant instead of "magic strings".  Define `private static final String rectangleShape = "rectangle"` and then use that consistently.

Comment: I know, it's just example, look at idea

Comment: @Sergey: it's just an example, but the mistakes are real.  How are we to know which mistakes are in your actual code and which aren't?  Any given mistake may be the actual reason your code isn't working, from our point of view.  Anyway try using `.equals()` and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `shape == "oval"` with `"oval".equals(shape)`. In Java, Strings that are equal according to `equals()` are not necessarily equal according to `==`.

Also, I'd suggest you replace the string literals with constants:

```
class Whatever {
    private final static String OVAL = "oval";

    public void process(String arg) {
        if (OVAL.equals(arg)) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

to avoid problems with spelling mistakes (like you have with "rectangle" and "rectanle").

You could add debugging statements to check that the `actionPerformed` method is actually being called, and to see when `paintComponent` is executed and trace what path it takes through your code.

By the way, the code as posted shouldn't compile: you have mismatched braces.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `markCompletelyDirty(myComponent)` on `javax.swing.RepaintManager`.